# Gradient Computation broken by Sigmoid function in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Hey I have been struggling with this weird problem. Here is my code for the Neural Net:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv_3d_=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(1,1,9,1,4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(1,1,9,1,4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(1,1,9,1,4),
            nn.LeakyReLU()  
        )

        self.linear_layers_ = nn.Sequential(

            nn.Linear(batch_size*32*32*32,batch_size*32*32*3),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(batch_size*32*32*3,batch_size*32*32*3),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self,x,y,z):
        conv_layer = x + y + z
        conv_layer = self.conv_3d_(conv_layer)
        conv_layer = torch.flatten(conv_layer)
        conv_layer = self.linear_layers_(conv_layer)
        conv_layer = conv_layer.view((batch_size,3,input_sizes,input_sizes))
        return conv_layer
```

The weird problem I am facing is that running this NN gives me an error

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [3072]], which is output 0 of SigmoidBackward, is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

The stack trace shows that the issue is in line

```
conv_layer = self.linear_layers_(conv_layer)
```

However, if I replace the last activation function of my FCN from nn.Sigmoid() to nn.LeakyRelu(), the NN executes properly.

Can anyone tell me why Sigmoid activation function is causing my backward computation to break?

Comment: Does the error also appear if you execute on your CPU? Also, can you reproduce this issue for a [mcve] including a smaller sample (and downsized kernels)?

Comment: No, I have not tried it on a cpu. I will try to make a minimum reproducible example @dennlinger

Comment: I think the problem is outside the `forward()` function, and most likely relates to how `x,y,z` are declared and reused between training steps. That error messages is basically saying that one of these variables was modified unexpectedly. So I'm thinking this works on the first forward call, but not the next forward calls.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem with my code. I delved deeper into what [in-place](https://towardsdatascience.com/in-place-operations-in-pytorch-f91d493e970e) actually meant. So, if you check the line

```
conv_layer = self.linear_layers_(conv_layer)
```

*linear_layers_* of the assignment is changing the values of conv_layer in-place and as a result the values are getting overwritten and because of this, gradient computation fails. Easy solution for this problem is to use the clone() function

i.e.

```
conv_layer = self.linear_layers_(conv_layer).clone()
```

This creates a copy of the right hand computation and Autograd is able to store the reference of the computation graph.